# Can you assign a dataframe to one dataframe cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nested

I search the forum and see that it's possible to assign a list to a df cell, but can you assign one df to a df cell (i.e. nest dataframe to dataframe?)

```
    A              B                     C   
0  Rep1   df_sales1(dataframe)  df_bonus1(dataframe)
1  Rep2   df_sales2(dataframe)  df_bonus2(dataframe)
```

Based on @ Mohamed Thasin ah below, I tried the following;

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size = (3,3)), columns = ['A','B','C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size = (3,3)), columns = ['A','B','C'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10, size = (3,3)), columns = ['A','B','C'])
dfs = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [0,1,2], 'dfs':[df1, df2, df3]})

dfs
   idx              dfs
0   0   A B C 0 3 4 6 1 3 5 5 2 6 2 5
1   1   A B C 0 2 9 9 1 6 5 5 2 9 1 1
2   2   A B C 0 3 7 2 1 8 5 1 2 9 4 8
```

Now I create another df_extra,

```
df_extra = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,100, size= (2,2)), columns = ['extra1', 'extra2'])
df_extra

  extra1  extra2
0   60      86
1   97      75
```

Now I tried to add another column in the original df, and add the df_extra to that column, say in the second row. This is where I run into problems. I tried different method to add this df_extra as list as follows;

```
dfs.loc[1,'extra'] = [df_extra]
```

this creates error:

```
......
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How should I do that to get the following:

```
   idx              dfs                   extra
0   0   A B C 0 3 4 6 1 3 5 5 2 6 2 5      NaN
1   1   A B C 0 2 9 9 1 6 5 5 2 9 1 1    **[df_extra]**  
2   2   A B C 0 3 7 2 1 8 5 1 2 9 4 8      NaN
```

Comment: You can keep dfs in to list and access based on the requirement. Any reason why you want to use dataframe to store dataframes?

Comment: I have quite many dfs so I'm trying to consolidate them by setting up nested data structure for easy management. Based on your recommendation I did some trial but still couldn't get the assignment work properly. I will add to the question of what I have tried.